# Brother MFC7360N keeps saying "replace toner"

Tags: laser-printer, toner

We've just replaced the toner cartridge of our Brother MFC7360N, but the printer keeps displaying the message `replace toner`, what should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open the front panel
2. Press the `clear` button, the display will show: `REPLACE DRUM? 1. Yes 2. No`
3. Type `*00` on the keypad, you should see `accepted` on the display.
4. Close the front panel

(From [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/53865-reset-toner-counter-on-brother-mfc-7460dn))

Comment: Joril, superhero!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the front panel
2. press the clear button (display will show: replace drum 1.yes 2. no)
3. press the * star button, NOT the # button.
4. you should see "accepted" on the panel.

I just did it and it worked.

Comment: This is really a tweak to Joril's answer rather than a new solution.  I'll also wager that you won't see "excepted" on the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, follow the steps given above; except press the "clear" key instead of the absent "back" key:

1. Open the front panel
2. Press the "clear", the display will show: `REPLACE DRUM? 1. Yes 2. No`
3. Type `*00` on the keypad, you should see `accepted` on the display.
4. Close the front panel

Comment: DAR, thanks for adding the advice.  In this Q&A format, answers are intended to be complete solutions, with each answer providing a new one.  Generally, minor clarification or improvement is done in a comment, which requires a little more rep.  However, you could suggest the additional information as an edit to Joril's answer since it clarifies it and makes it more complete.

Comment: @fixer1234 corrected my answer

Answer (score -1):

Correction

Open the front panel
Press the "clear", the display will show: REPLACE DRUM? 1. Yes 2. No 
**press the # button** THEN
Type *00 on the keypad, you should see accepted on the display.

Now you are good to go!

Comment: This answer attracted the downvote probably because answers are intended to be complete solutions and each answer should contribute another solution.  Corrections to another answer should be done in a comment, which requires a little more rep.  You could also propose an edit to the other answer.